# Subs from VB.Net in Python

Tags: python

In VB.NET you could do this..
You had a sub like this:

```
 Private Sub RandomSub()
     'blablabla
 End Sub


 Private Sub Button1_Click(Byval.. Byref..) As Button1.Click
      RandomSub()
 End Sub
```

How do you make subs in python and call them when you want? I know about the 
**DEF** thing but is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's it. You can use `lambda`s as well

Comment: Yes. And they are usually called functions or [subroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine).

Comment: @ForceBru better not to confuse beginners with lambda functions.

Comment: @BasSwinckels, perhaps it's better to show them all the power of Python including lambda functions so they can see that their efforts are worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can define a function or a method using the `def` keyword like you said, but there is no way to truly do what `Sub` does in VB.Net. You should return any relevant values from the function and assign them to variables in the calling function.

```
def RandomSub():
    rndstring = "something"
    return rndstring

def Button1_Click(param1, param2):
    rndstring = RandomSub()
    # use rndstring here
```

You can also return tuples from a function and unpack them in an assignment statement

```
def RandomSub():
    var1 = "something"
    var2 = "something"
    var3 = "something"
    return var1,var2,var3

def Button1_Click(param1, param2):
    rndstring1,rndstring2,rndstring3 = RandomSub()
    # use rndstrings here
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of problem using 'def'...
When I do something like rndstring="something...." and look for it outside the function it says that i never created that string.. and it cant find the string... ERROR: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'smjena' referenced before assignment..

Comment: Oh, okay I misunderstood what `Sub` actually does. Now that I have a better idea, I don't believe there's anything in the python language that quite replicates that functionality. You should return any necessary values from the function and assign the return values. I'll update my answer to try to better explain this

Comment: Ok, I fixed it.. the problem was that I wasn't returning the variable that I needed but only assigning it in the function itself. In other words it did not exist outside the functions.. So I did this MyString = func(...stufff...).. beofre that it was just func(..stuff...)

Comment: I see you're not really met with Subs from Vb.NET.. the big difference that a function in VB.NET MUST return something otherwise it'd make no sense to use it.. a function will process the given information and return something.. a SUB will just run some code and do whatever you say in it... it can modify values outside and inside itself.. it is a whole different thing..

Comment: Right, I understood that when you talked about being able to reference an assignment outside of the function's scope. You need to assign the return value to something, which I see you now understand

Answer (score 0):

I read the conversation below wilbur's answer, but I thought I'd add an answer that directly addresses the question, just for future stackoverflow readers.

In VB `Sub` is different than `Function`. A `Sub` is a block of re-usable code that doesn't return anything, while a `Function` is a block of code that returns a value. In Python (and most other programming languages), a "function" is a block of code that can optionally return a value. Thus, in Python you use `def` in place of VB's `Sub` and `Function`.

Also, in VB you must declare the return type of a `Function`, while in Python you don't.

Thus:

```
Private Sub RandomSub()
    'Do something
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RandomSub()
End Sub
```

Would in Python be something like:

```
def _random_sub():
    # Do something

def _button1_click(sender, e):
    _random_sub()
```